# Variables posting twice

Tags: variables

I wish to create a new variable as described in the codex, but on submission of the URL the variables are submitted twice to my function

I have tried this within a plugin also a the `function.php`. I have also tried to use `wp_reset_query()`

Here is my sample code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_function');
function my_function ($vars) {    
  $vars[] = 'Q1';
  $vars[] = 'Q2';    
  return $vars;    
}

add_action('parse_query', 'query_var');    
function query_var () {    
  if (get_query_var('Q1')){    
    echo ('hello');    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parse_query` action gets called on *every query* (menu items, sidebar recent posts widgets, etc.), but `get_query_var` pulls from the *main query*, so that condition will be true for all queries despite the fact that the query var doesn't exist in those queries. You need to check the query object passed to your function hooked to `parse_query`:

```
add_action('parse_query', 'query_var'); 
function query_var( $query ) { 
  if ( isset( $query->query_vars['Q1'] ) ){    
    echo ('hello');    
  }
}
```